# Why can I copy std::unique_ptr into another one without using std::move?

Tags: c++, std, unique-ptr

std::unique_ptr shouldn't be copied to another std::unique_ptr unless you use std::move, correct?

But I experience something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class ClassA{
public:

    ClassA() {
        cout << "created" << endl;
    }

    ~ClassA() {
        cout << "destroyed" << endl;
    }



    void print() {
        cout << "ok" << endl;
    }

};

void test() {

    unique_ptr<ClassA> b(new ClassA());

    b->print();

    // unique_ptr<ClassA> d(b); this won't compile since you can't copy unique_ptr

    ClassA& aa = *b;  // ClassA aa = *b; works too.

    unique_ptr<ClassA> d(&aa); // but this can, why is that

    d->print();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    test();

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs ok, Output is:

```
created
ok
ok
destroyed
destroyed
```

ClassA got destroyed twice, how does this happen?  Should it crash because of nothing to delete?

Comment: Think about the name. If you can make a copy of something, is it still *unique*?

Comment: `ClassA aa = *b;` would be different -- then `d` refers to automatic storage and will cause undefined behaviour when it tries to delete that storage.  Both cases are UB but for different reasons

Answer (score 6):

When you do `std::unique_ptr<ClassA> d(&aa);`, you are creating `d` using a raw pointer. The `unique_ptr` constructor can't see that you are passing it a pointer to an object which is already owned/managed by another `std::unique_ptr`.

Hence the double delete, which causes undefined behavior, i.e. anything can happen.

Comment: I understand now. one of my concerns is double delete won't crash or generate any issues, then this bug is pretty hard to catch if written.

Comment: @xkimi you've always got to think about object lifetimes when initializing named references. The reference might outlive the original object whose lifetime is controlled in a different manner

Comment: @M.M I found something interesting. I can still call print() after object get reset()

Comment: @xkimi undefined behaviour means anything can happen

Comment: Also your print doesn't refer to the object in any way so is less likely to crash. If you were to have a member variable and you printed that, it would probably crash, but being UB, it might work, or might print some rubbish values...